# import bootstrap in angular 6 angular.json Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

What is the correct way to import bootstrap in Angular 6. In previous versions I did it this way and it worked correctly.

**angular-cli.json** (Angular 5)

```
"styles": [
    "styles.scss"
  ],
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
```

**angular.json** (Angular 6)

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
"scripts": [
          "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
          "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

get error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/pacozevallos/myApp/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This configuration should work because as you see in `angular.json` file there is property `"root": "",` for importing files, so follow below piece of code

```
"styles": [
   "src/styles.scss",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
   "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

Comment: This works for me I'm just seeing some changes of angular 6 thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I see your error is showing a jquery file missing. But the bootstrap 4 does not need jquery. If you are using the command 
`npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` from angular-cli I think is not need for a jquery dependency.
Also need to add to the main module and the module that you want to implement the bootstrap styling the import statement:

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

It is not necessary to install jquery, might interfere with ng-bootstrap code.
Maybe you need to remove any jquery that you may installed.

Comment: The OP was talking about `bootstrap` from `getbootstrap.com`, not `ng-bootstrap`