# dropdown does not open with Angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, npm, dropdown

I'm learning Angular and I have a problem with Bootstrap and the dropdown.

The Bootstrap class loads well, but the dropdown does not work, that's what I did for my new project Angular:

```
npm install bootstrap jquery popper --save
```

And when I do a npm audit here is the result

https://codepen.io/Anduril53/pen/LoPgyz?editors=1010

styles in angular.json

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.scss",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],
```

Comment: And you also added jQuery, bootstrap and popper js to the `angular.json` file..!

Comment: no, not in angular.json
Here is my file:
https://codepen.io/Anduril53/pen/MdgzWm?editors=1010

Where should I add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

https://github.com/lichunbin814/angular_bootstarp_dropdown

```
    "styles": [
      "src/styles.scss",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ],
```

Comment: I try but here is the return when I do ng serve and npm install popper --save

http://prntscr.com/nkbsl5

Comment: This may help you ([import-bootstrap-in-angular-6-angular-json-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-direct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50280575/import-bootstrap-in-angular-6-angular-json-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-direct/50281113))

Comment: I find the answer. I install popper and not popper.js, so the problem is solved.
By cons I have some dependency error, how to solve them easily?

Comment: I change the order of importing js file (popper.js have to before bootstrap's js)

Comment: The message were a problem with a dependence of bootstrap, but is now solved

Answer (score -1):

why are using bootstrap .. you can use Angular material it's an awesome framework for angular it has a many features and its easy to work with it .
stpes: 
1- install the pack 
    npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations

2- integrate angular material to your project 
    ng add @angular/material

3- restart the server (ng serve)

4- now you can use any component of angular material. this is the link 
   https://material.angular.io/components/categories

5- for example if you want a dropdown you need to add the api (a module) of the              select component in the app module after that you can use it in the all app .

to use the select component : 
     1- add the api in the app module 
     import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';

```
imports : [MatSelectModule]
```

2- go to the the any component on your project and add the component

heyy

Comment: The question is about bootstrap. If you want to propose another library, you can propose it in a comment but it's not an answer!